# Turtle graphics setpos() does nothing

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

For some reason my code works until it gets to line 67 (bold text). The cursor should move down 100px on the y axis but it stays there and draws the boxes over the second darkblue one. Does anybody know why that is. Help would be gladly appreciated. I'm still new to Python.

```
def drawbox():
    for x in range (4):
        avo.color('white', 'blue')
        avo.begin_fill()

        for x in range(2):
            avo.forward(400)
            avo.right(90)
            avo.forward(100)
            avo.right(90)
        avo.end_fill()

        avo.penup()
        avo.setpos(0,-100)
        avo.pendown()

        avo.color('white', 'darkblue')
        avo.begin_fill()
        for x in range(2):
            avo.forward(400)
            avo.right(90)
            avo.forward(100)
            avo.right(90)
        avo.end_fill()

        avo.penup()
        **avo.setpos(0,-100)**
        avo.pendown()
        continue


    turtle.done()


drawbox()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `setpos()` works in *absolute* positions whereas you want to move to a position *relative* to where you are now.  By doing:

```
avo.setpos(0,-100)
```

You always return to the same spot on the screen.  Try changing both of your `setpos()` calls to instead do:

```
avo.sety(avo.ycor() - 100)
```

Or, better yet, redesign your program slightly to point the turtle in the right direction and simply move forward 100 pixels after each box:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def drawboxes():
    turtle.setheading(270)

    for _ in range(2):
        for fill_color in ('blue', 'darkblue'):
            turtle.fillcolor(fill_color)
            turtle.begin_fill()

            for _ in range(2):
                turtle.forward(100)
                turtle.left(90)
                turtle.forward(400)
                turtle.left(90)

            turtle.end_fill()

            turtle.penup()
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.pendown()

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.pencolor('white')

drawboxes()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works as i wanted.